# iphone target might include its own product

Tags: iphone

After adding image resource into app (and may be some step I do not remember about) xcode reports with message: this target might contain its own product

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

thank you

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

1. Open the "Products" group in the Groups & Files pane, click on the .app file
2. Right click -> "Get Info"
3. In the "Targets" section, make sure the .app file is **not** checked